# should tags 'numberformat' and 'numberformatting' be combined?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not sure what the tags were intended for originally, as neither of them have wikis. If NumberFormatting is for displaying numbers to users and **numberformat** is for discussion of short,long,double,float there needs a bit of documentation.